# How can I verify that $\langle a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n, b_1e_1+\cdots+b_ne_n\rangle = a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n$ is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

In Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra done right, he says that if we let $U$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and let $T \in U$, then an inner product on $U$ is

$\langle a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n, b_1e_1+\cdots+b_ne_n\rangle = a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n$

and he claims that this is very easy to verify.

The only problem is, I am used to verifying inner products on arbitrary vectors like $v,u,w$, etc. and am thrown off by the way he defined it.

How can I verify that the above is ineeded an inner product space? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is $\{e_i\}$ an \emph{orthonormal basis}. If yes then... the answer below is relevant.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy he has seen it in Axler's book and Axler define ${{\{e_i\}}_{1}}^{n}$ to be orthonormal.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to assume is that $E=\{ e_{1},e_{2},\cdots e_{n}\}$ is a basis of $U$. By the definition of a basis, every $x\in U$ corresponds to a unique column vector $[x]_{E}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with
$$
      [x]_{E}=\left[\begin{array}{c}x_{1}\\x_{2}\\ \vdots \\ x_{n}\end{array}\right]
$$ such that $x=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}e_{j}$. The map $x \in U \rightarrow [x]_{E}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a linear bijection. The inner-product Axler has defined is induced from the inner-product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ through this bijection. Explicitly,
$$
             (x,y)= [y]_{E}^{T}\,[x]_{E},
$$
where the expression on the right is usual matrix multiplication of the row vector $[y]_{E}^{T}$ (transpose of $[y]_{E}$) and the column vector $[x]_{E}$. The linearity of $(x,y)$ in $x$ or in $y$ follows from the linearity of matrix operations, etc.. Give a name to this bijection, say $L : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and you'll be able to easily verify that $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is an inner-product on $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $e_i$'s are mutually orthogonal so use the linearity of the inner product and the fact that $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $\langle e_i,e_i\rangle=1$.

Comment: Do I need to show: positivity, definiteness, additivity in first slot, homogeneity in first slot, conjugate symmetry etc?

Comment: Bad answer. $e_i$ are mutually orthogonal because of the definition, he cannot use this in a proof

Comment: @5xum what do you mean by saying that he can't use this in the proof? can't one use a definition in the proof?

Comment: @user136503 the moment you say that you have an inner product, all those things come with the definition of the inner product itself.

Comment: @wanderer But to use the properties of an inner product you first need to verify that you actually have an inner product...